# What is char * const *?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

So it seems like it means `a pointer to a constant pointer to char`. That is it points to a `char * const`, so far so good.

What gets me confused is where and how I saw it used. I was looking at the man page for [`qsort`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) and the example does the following to convert the pointers to elements of a `char **` (an array of strings), (pointers to elements seen as `const void *`) to normal char pointers feedable to `strcmp`:

```
static int
cmpstringp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    /* The actual arguments to this function are "pointers to
       pointers to char", but strcmp(3) arguments are "pointers
       to char", hence the following cast plus dereference */
    return strcmp(* (char * const *) p1, * (char * const *) p2);
}
```

My question is, why is there a cast to `char * const *`? Why isn't it just a `const char **` (because eventually we want to send a `const char *` to `strcmp`)?

Comment: I got the answer as soon as I finished typing it (D'oh)

Comment: You should check out http://cdecl.org/ - it converts "C gibberish" to English, and vice versa :)

Comment: @Polynomial, yeah I know that. Understanding the type was not really a problem. I just didn't know how to put a summary of this question in the title. Feel free to edit the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char * const *` indeed means a pointer to a constant pointer to chars. The reason this cast is performed in the code in the question is the following:

`p1` and `p2` are (non-const) pointers to a constant location. Let's assume the type of this location is `const T`.

Now we want to cast `p1` and `p2` to their real types. We know that each element of the array is a `char *`, therefore `T = char *`. That is `const T` is a constant pointer to char, which is written as `char * const`.

Since `p1` and `p2` are pointers to the elements of the array, they are of type `const T *`, which is `char * const *`.

Since the function merely calls `strcmp`, in truth it wouldn't have made any difference if the parameters were cast to `char **` or `const char **` or `const char * const *` or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

When a function declares that it takes a pointer-to-const elements (e.g. `strcmp()`) it means that the function promises not to mody the elements via the pointer, it does not mean that the parameters passed to that function must be pointers-to-const themselves.

Remember: the `const` modifier is a contract term, basically meaning that the declaring function promises not to modify the element the `const` modifies.  Conversion in the direction of non-const -> const therefore is usually OK.